# Why is ubuntu getting restarted after replacing Intel e6600 with Intel x6800 processor?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, overheating

I was previously using Intel Core 2 Duo Processor E6600 along with Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows XP Service Pack 3. It was working great. Later, I changed my processor to Intel Core 2 Extreme X6800 and Ubuntu is getting restarted over and over again (whereas Windows XP SP3 is working great). There is a black screen with some information on it. It is remaining for about 30 secs and then boom! restart. I managed to take a pic of the screen. 
[image]

I formatted and re-installed Ubuntu, but the problem persisted.

My detailed system configuration is as follows:-
Processor: Intel Core 2 Extreme X6800 (from Intel Core 2 Duo E6600),
RAM: 3 GB DDR2,
HDD: 80 GB 7200 RPM,
OS Installed: Windows XP SP3 alongside Ubuntu 13.10.

Another thing I would like to mention is that, when I replaced the processor I applied Arctic Silver 5 on the processor before fitting the heat sink and fan. And if it is heat problem, how come is XP working perfectly?

Update: I tried to install Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit). The computer restarted in the middle of the installation. The screen went black along with some messages on it (which I did not understand). It stayed that way for about 30 secs. Then the computer restarted.

Comment: To add a screen shot click on the `edit` button ---> Go to the bar below your question's title and there is an icon to upload pictures.

Comment: Is installing a newer and supported version of Ubuntu an option?

Comment: 13.10 is beyond end of life and thus no longer supported. Try a more recent version of Ubuntu and post the error messages you get when you boot. Otherwise simply stating it does not work makes it difficult to impossible to answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Ok sir, I will try to install Ubuntu Version 15.04 today. After that, I will upload the results.

Comment: @Hunter: Sir, I am not able to find any bar below my question title.

Comment: @Dan: Sir, I will try to install the newer version.

Comment: @Hunter: Sir, thank you for your detailed guidance. Now, I understood how to upload a pic.

Comment: @Hunter: Sir, I am facing a problem while trying to upload images. As I am new, I have only 1 reputation whereas the edit page is giving an error that I need at least 10 reputation to upload images.

Comment: upvoted, +5,  now you can add the image